# Why I ever should use a Kerbodyne S3-14400 Tank?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

The Kerbodyne S3-14400 fuel tank's statistic is just the double in anything I'm considering so far of the Kerbodyne S3-7200 Tank. It costs twice as much money, is twice as high, contains twice as much fuel. So it seems (to me) to be the same as just connectiong 2 Kerbodyne S3-7200 Tank with each other.

The only difference I can see, is:
It is an additional node of the tech tree requiring 500 science to invest for unlocking as the highend invention of fuel tanks, while the S3-7200 Tank is an inexchangable prerequirement of it. So why I should ever spent 500 science to receive a part, I'm unavoidable allready able to exactly build my self of preavailable parts (namely: 2x Kerbodyne S3-7200 Tank)?

Comment: @vianna77: At that point of progress I'd assume it is unusual to not have fully upgraded the launchplattform allready, or even if not, prefering it over "*wasting*" 500 science. But true point, it could be used to reduce parts due to lag reduction. But that's on the otherhand something that shouldn't be sold as the only reward of an ingame purchase. So that shouldn't be the only point, should it?

Comment: There is no point at all to it, you miss nothing. Career and its Tech Tree is relatively new in KSP. Tech Tree itself was made without much reasoning (wheels are later than rockets) only because something was needed for new modes, and it did not change much over time. There are mods with Realistic Tech Trees, so you can "fix" it if you want.

Answer (score 7):

Substituting two smaller fuel tanks with a larger one reduces the part count of your vessel. This can matter when you haven't yet fully upgraded your VAB and SPH.

A lower part count also improves game performance and prevents physics bugs which come from too many parts and lead to unexplained wobbling and explosions. Less connections also leads to more overall stability of your vessel.

But I still wouldn't consider that tech node a priority. There are far more useful tech nodes in that price segment.

Comment: So as discussed allready in the comments, the only reason why I should unlock it, is if my computers hardware isn't well enough or I'm encountering physic bugs? So paying with ingame currency to fix out of "universe" problems? Sounds like a bad game-design decission to me.

Comment: @vianna77 structural integrity and/or aerodynamic profile of your design will be inferior. You will either have higher, unwieldy and bending, stack (upper stage engine+decoupler) with more potential failure points (connection between parts) or wider stack (asparagus), inducing more drag, with radial decoupling requiring more complex engineering (failure points, mass, parts, ugly). You can always "fix" it with [more struts](https://i.imgur.com/7JTqnht.png) but it will have problems on its own. Do not forget, mass will cost you in Delta-V.

Comment: @vianna77 This was true until the aerodynamics overhaul in version 1.0. Now asparagus designs have atmospheric drag problems due to their width. But that's an issue for a different question. Please try to stay on-topic when commenting on questions and answers. If you would like to change the subject, ask a new question.